# Not getting expected date

Tags: php, wordpress

My php code is returning 1970-01-02 instead of the entered date of birth.
I'm using the following code:

```
$date_of_birth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_of_birth', true ))));
```

Comment: What is the output of get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_of_birth', true )?

Comment: @Samir i guess the value is `1970-01-01`

Comment: proper manipulation of date is not hapenning in `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_of_birth', true ))`. Can you add that code??

Comment: @Niranjan output will be `1970-01-01` if there is some problem with the date. so we need the output from function `get_post_meta`

Comment: @Samir i got what you are telling. see my previous comment.

Comment: Could you specify the version of PHP you're using?

Comment: You will get the output `1970-01-01` if `strtotime` cannot understand the data format you are giving it so `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_of_birth', true )` is not returning a date or the date in not in `English date format`. Because you add a day to the first calc using `strtotime('+1 day',` you are getting this `1970-01-02` date returned. **So what does** `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_of_birth', true )` **actually return???** Understand that and you will be able to fix your issue

Comment: get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_of_birth', true ) is returning a date in this format.....Sun Dec 25 1988 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) Note:

> Prior to PHP 5.1.0, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
>   therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix
>   epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work
>   on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating
>   systems.

So I suspect this problem is somewhat related to your PHP version and also your OS. Could you specify all these information?

Regards,